# c# Dynamic textbox control with CheckBox and List

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox

Yesterday, I asked a similar question and people told me to use a List and a controller object.  I changed my code accordingly now added a MyContols Class and a List in order to control my items in a better way.

This is my class which hold my checkbox and textboxes:

```
    private List<MyControls> _myControls = new List<MyControls>();

    class MyControls
      {
    int x=5;
    int y=30; 
    public CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    public TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();

    public TextBox tbSpecs = new TextBox();
    public TextBox tb3 = new TextBox();
    public TextBox tb4 = new TextBox();



    public void initElements(String name)
    {
        cb.Width = 10;
        cb.Height = 10;
        cb.Name = "cb_" + name;
        cb.Location = new Point(x, y+5);
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(cb);
        x += 15;

        tb1.Width = 50;
        tb1.Height = 20;
        tb1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        tb1.Name = "tb1_" + name;
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tb1);
        x += 60;

        tbSpecs.Width = 150;
        tbSpecs.Height = 20;
        tbSpecs.Name = "tb2_" + name;
        tbSpecs.Location = new Point(x, y);
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tbSpecs);
        x += 160;

        tb3.Width = 40;
        tb3.Height = 20;
        tb3.Name = "tb3_" + name;
        tb3.Location = new Point(x, y);
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tb3);
        x += 50; 

        tb4.Width = 450;
        tb4.Height = 20;
        tb4.Name = "tb4_" + name;
        tb4.Location = new Point(x, y);
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tb4);

        x = 0;
    }

    public int SetX(int i)
    {
        x = i;
        return x;
    }

    public int SetY(int Y)
    {
        y = Y;
        return y;
    }

}
```

also I have a ProductForm Class which is a second from in my application which let me view data in textboxes and edit and delete these data.

My problem is how can I delete a row?

My Second question is for each row do I have to create a new instance of my MyControl class? Probably my questions are very simple. Sorry for taking your time guys!

This function is just for test purposes because I am still trying to add an delete my rows.

```
        public void CreateFormElements()
        {
        ProductForm form2 = new ProductForm();
        form2.Visible = true;
        form2.Activate();

        MyControls mc = new MyControls();

        _myControls.Add(mc);
        _myControls[0].initElements("1");
        mc = new MyControls();
        _myControls.Add(mc);

        mc.SetY(55);
        _myControls[1].initElements("2");



    }
```

How can I delete an entire row if the checkbox corresponding is selected?

can you tell me a code which can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Init, add a handler for cb.Checked event and then delete the row.

In Init:

```
 cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;
```

Handler - not sure of the exact implementation in your case but here is some rough code:

```
private void cb_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string NameSet  = (sender as CheckBox).Name.Split(new char[]{'_'})[1];
   Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Remove("ch_" + NameSet);
   Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Remove("tb1_" + NameSet);
   Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Remove("tb2_" + NameSet);
   Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Remove("tb3_" + NameSet);
   Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Remove("tb4_" + NameSet);


}
```

Comment: can you write me a code how to add a cb.Checked and delete row code ??

Comment: I am getting error for Remove Method. It says cannot conver string to System.Windows.Forms.Control

Comment: You'll likely need to do something like Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Remove(Form.ActiveForm.Controls.FindControl("ch_" + NameSet));

Comment: Joe finally I prepared my code :) Many thanks for your great help and assistance. Now I am heading towards the next step in my code.